# c++ malloc() keeps assigning to same memory address

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, malloc

I'm trying to  create "nodes" iteratively using memory. My code currently just says what address it goes to, and does not actually try to make the links in the linked list.

Here's the code for a `node`:

```
struct node {
  int num;
  node *next;
};
```

Here's the code for `malloc()`

```
node *etc = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
etc->num = 1;
etc->next = NULL;
cout << etc << endl;

for (int i=2; i<=10; i++) {
  node *new_etc;
  new_etc = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
  cout << new_etc << endl;
}
```

## EDIT

Output:

```
0xcff010
0xcff030
0xcff050
0xcff070
0xcff090
0xcff0b0
0xcff0d0
0xcff0f0
0xcff110
0xcff130
```

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: @JohnDibling: `cout` qualifies as C++ even the most procedural code ever. :)

Comment: Use `new`/`delete`, instead of `malloc`/`free`. Or write plain C.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Ah, yes, didn't see the `cout`, only saw the `malloc`.

Comment: I removed the [tag:c++] tag, since it's closer to [tag:c].

Comment: I retract my previous question and submit a new one:  Why are you using `malloc`/`free`?

Comment: @MarcClaesen: actually, I think that the C++ tag is relevant, since the problem here is related mostly to how he's printing the data, which happens to be the only part where he's using C++ facilities.

Comment: Hmm. I'll be a good boy and retag it ... It looks like the question is already answered, though. :)

Comment: @MarcClaesen:  This is not C since he's using `cout`, and now there is no language tag at all.  It should be tagged C++, and JShoe should be prepared to defend his use of `malloc`/`free`.

Comment: @JohnDibling: The language tag will be back shortly, I'm still too wee little to get it readjusted instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_etc = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
...
free(new_etc);
```

Why shouldn't `malloc` return the same block next time round, if you `free`d it already?
It should be hot in cache, so may well be the best choice.

If you don't `free` the memory, *and* you fix your logging, what happens?

Comment: Okay, I removes the `free()`. Nothing changed though.

Comment: So you fixed the `free` _and_ the `logging`, compiled the code _exactly_ as shown in your edited question, and still get the same output?

Comment: I'm sorry. I made a change in the question, and not my code. You're correct, and now it works. Thanks.

Comment: The meaning of "it works" quite eludes me, what wasn't working before... ?

Answer (score 3):

```
cout << &new_etc << endl;
```

Here you are printing the address of the variable `new_etc`, i.e. the location of memory where *the pointer* is stored, not the address to where it points. What you want is:

```
cout << new_etc << endl;
```

where you print the *content* of `new_etc`, i.e. the address that `malloc` returned.

Now, since you are `free`ing this memory after each iteration, you may get different addresses as well as the same one - after all, if you freed the memory `malloc` gave you in the past, it means that it can be reused.

Comment: Um, OP `free`s the memory immediately after logging, so `malloc` would be entirely justified in returning the same block again next time.

Comment: Okay, I removes the `free()`. Nothing changed though.

Comment: @JShoe: either you didn't remove the `&` or you didn't remove the `free` (or simply, you removed them but didn't recompile). As you can see e.g. [here](http://ideone.com/j2ch1d), the addresses *are* different.

Answer (score 1):

To print the address of a pointer, drop `&`:

```
cout << &new_etc << endl;
        ^
```

It prints the address of pointer `new_etc`, not the address where `new_etc` points to. The address of `new_etc` is same and will not change after assigning a pointer to it.

***After edited question :*** See this [live code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=8da1815ea7e81945f7bdcef5649d33a0-83e866535a38890f283077ce45ff5373) which shows different addresses. So, you're output is not related to the code you're showing us.